# Button that changes it's position/css when clicked and can toggle between show/hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need 3 buttons that can toggle between show/hide text. When clicked on the button, the button will get smaller (change css) and slide to another position, so the text can be shown at the buttons previous position. Example below:

```
jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/1/
```

The toggle function show/hide text is not the problem. The problem is the function to change the buttons css, when clicked.

Comment: You can fool SO, but not us humans!

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: @MadsRisager SO doesn't allow to post links to jsfiddle.net without code. You can fool SO by formatting the link as code, but you can't stop humans from voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way that I can think of is to toggle a class on the button which has the specific styling you wish to apply when the button is clicked.

In your fiddle, it would simply be adding something similar to this in your toggle function.

```
$(this).toggleClass('clickedButton');
```

Here is a fiddle based on yours:
http://jsfiddle.net/sm66aLL1/